# Sharepoint 2013 - How to create a 2-dimensional view?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

It's that I have some business data originally stored in an Excel file, with something like the following,

http://tinypic.com/r/5l5beq/8

any suggestion to presenting the above formatted data in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be possible using Power BI. However better option would be I would publish the excel on SharePoint with office web app server that way user can easily see the pivot.